# Why Is the "library" line needed for Dart?

Tags: dart

For a library file (say `foo.dart`), you start it with a line like this:

```
library my_foo_lib;
```

Why is it needed? The import is based on file name (`foo.dart`), not library string (`my_foo_lib`):

```
import 'package:foo.dart';
```

Having to declare library seems redundant and error-prone. Is there a good reason behind it?

Comment: What if there were two libraries in the file?

Comment: Not quite sure what you mean by having two libraries in the file. Can you elaborate?

Answer (score 2):

You can omit the `library` statement then it is an implicitly named library with an empty string as name but when you import a library you need to name it explicitly otherwise you get an error that you have several libraries with the same name.

- Identifiers starting with an `_` (underline) are private. Privacy in Dart is per library.
- The `part of` references the library name.
- When you use reflection to look up classes or functions you include the library name. This way you can differentiate classes with the same name in different libraries.
- [Dart Programming Language Specification](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-408.htm) (17 Libraries and Scripts) also says 
  "The name may be relevant for further language evolution."

Comment: Why isn't the library implicitly set to file name then? Is there a reason why setting to empty string is better?

Comment: Honestly, I don't know. You could ask at https://groups.google.com/a/dartlang.org/forum/#!forum/misc